# SQL Server error "SQL Server does not exist or access denied"

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I have a VB6 application with an SQL Server 2008 database. It works fine on my developer workstation, of course, but when I deployed it in a freshly installed operating system (a virtual machine), an error occurs saying:

[image]

Additional info:

I tried to deploy it in another computer (not fresh install and not a VM) and it works fine.

Here is my connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=GS3-LNUBLA\LESTERDB;Database=UPPC;User Id=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd;
```

Does it mean I have to install something before my application to work? If there is, what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean I have to install something before my application to work?

OBVIOUSLY not - the error is quite clear. If you would miss a driver for sql server, it would not be able to try to reach it.

Start checking the basics first, one by one.

- Can the server be reached? (ping)
- Is the proper port open to reach the instance (LESTERDB is an instance name)

I suspect either crappy configuration on the vm side (as another normal server works) or a firewall or routing issue. Server does not exist can mean machine not reachable, traffic blocked, wrong protocol configuration. Access denied obviously means exactlyx that.

Comment: Hi. I turned off the firewall for both client and server. The server can be reached. However, when I try to ping the server with the "-a" option, WORKGROUP is displayed instead of the server name. The error still occurs.

Comment: So, you have a totally non standard and wrong server setup. Please contact your IT department and have them sort that out within the policies of your employer (hint: we do not do system administration here and we assume you are a doing that in a professional capacity)